# C# xml writer checkbox checked

Tags: c#, html, xml, checkbox, checked

I built a program program that generates an html file with an xml file.
How do I make  to input type='checkbox' id='hi' checked/>?
How do I write that checked in C#? I did not find anything on google.
That's what I have:

```
XmlElement Check = doc.CreateElement("input");
                Check.SetAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                Check.SetAttribute("id", "hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add checked attribute with a value.

try this:

```
XmlElement Check = doc.CreateElement("input");
            Check.SetAttribute("type", "checkbox");
            Check.SetAttribute("id", "hi");
            Check.SetAttribute("checked", "1");
```

The value "1" is just a kind of cheating. It dot not have any impact.
If you do not want checked, delete the attribute "checked" completely from the element.

Comment: Well it would be right but this creates checked="1" not checked ^^

Comment: is your output not looking like this? if so it should work.                                                          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="1">

Comment: I just tried in a notepad with same statement and it worked.